# Using Python4Delphi in Delphi programs to execute Delphi code

Tags: delphi, testing, python4delphi

Good day everyone!

I have a question.
Perhaps someone has already experienced this.
I have a ready-made program on Delphi. And I need to initialize and execute all the functions of this program using a Python script.

Is it possible to accomplish this task only with the help of TPytnon components? Without adding memos and other things as shown in the demo programs.

Just run the script and get the result.

Maybe someone can help with this question. I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi

Comment: I know, where I can find Python4Delphi. I am asking about how to execute scripts without adding memos to already made program using Only TPython Components. Is it possible?

Comment: Why should it be _not_ possible? What have you tried so far and where do you fail? Your question contains neither PAS nor PY code.

Comment: An answer can be found on this crosspost: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6472-testing-with-python/?do=findComment&comment=57062